Bash string substitution - bug?
I am trying to do some file management in bash and
I have strings in this format:
1 dir/hello.txt
2 dir2/bar.jpg

When I run this substitution: ${FOO/[:space:]*/Hello}
I get this result: 1 dir/hHello
The goal is to substitute everything after the first
space (including the space) with Hello
Seems like a bug to me. In such a case, please confirm and
I will take the issue upstream.

That's not a regular expression, but a documented class in bash manpages:
$ man bash
...
 Within [ and ], character classes can be specified using the syntax [:class:], where
 class is one of the following classes defined in the POSIX standard:
 alnum alpha ascii blank cntrl digit graph lower print punct space upper word xdigit
 A character class matches any character belonging to that class.  The word character
 class matches letters, digits, and the character _.
...


The documentation is confusingly phrased. Character class can be specified by [:class:] within another set of square brackets [...]. So you need to use [[:space:]] to get the character class. Without the second set of brackets, [:space:] just matches the characters ":", "s", "p", etc, and in your example it's matching the "e" in "hello.txt". (And BTW this is true in both glob and regular expressions, but not in arguments to the tr command.)

You almost had it right. From your quote:

Within [ and ], character classes can be specified using the syntax [:class:], where class is one of the following classes defined in the POSIX standard: [...]

So, you need to double up on the square brackets:
s='1 dir/hello.txt'
echo "${s/[[:space:]]*/Hello}"

produces 1Hello.

Do you know where is this documented?
Even ChatGPT thought this was not possible and had to go to quite a depth to find what I have posted in my answer.
Now I don't like using LLMs for coding, but this was a really neat thing he pulled off.

@MarcelPlch You found the POSIX source, but the Bash manual isn't ambiguous about it, either. It says to use [:class:] within [...], which results in double brackets. [[ isn't special here: you could also have a bracket expression for "period, hex digits, and a hyphen" that looks like [.[:xdigit:]-].

@MarcelPlch  try: PAGER='less +/^[[:space:]]*pattern\ matching' man bash or the online manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html

Even ChatGPT was wrong? ChatGPT is often wrong, and it should never be surprising when it fails to "answer" a question.

(TLDR at the end.)
From OpenGroup POSIX specification:
in the locale definition, the expression "[[.ch.]]" shall be treated as an RE containing the collating symbol 'ch', while "[ch]" shall be treated as an RE matching 'c' or 'h'. Collating symbols are recognized only inside bracket expressions. If the string is not a collating element in the current locale, the expression is invalid.
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05
The solution was to use double brackets.
I will push upstream to document this better.
